# Is overstaying 90 day limit in USA by one day a problem?

Tags: usa, overstaying

My daughter has bought a return ticket to Hawaii which exceeds the 90 day limit by one day.  She intends to travel for the first month and do voluntary work on an organic farm for two months before she flies home.

Is outstaying the 90 day limit by one day going to be a problem?

Comment: If her length of stay is longer than she is allowed to stay in the USA, then the airline may not even let her board, as they are responsible for making sure the passenger meets entry requirements..

Comment: She should also note that the voluntary work for the organic farm could cause problems, if not evidenced properly. See this: http://london.usembassy.gov/mobile/b1.html

Comment: +1 to @CMaster 's comment.  The odds of volunteer work at an organic farm being allowed on VWP is very, very low...

Comment: indeed, you're not allowed to work on a tourist visa, and that includes volunteer work (visiting a trade show is usually allowed, if you're not there to sell things). And no, claiming it was "educational" isn't a loophole around that as you can't do education on a tourist visa either (except visiting conferences for a few days)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It's breaking the terms of the agreement between you and the country of the United States of America.

Getting out won't be a problem - there's no exit immigration, so she'll be able to leave.  However, overstaying is usually frowned upon, especially by the US, and it could cause her to have problems getting future visas for the US, or for other countries if they share the information.

Best option is to change the ticket, or apply for a longer visa than the 90 day VWP option.

Comment: Possibly also worth mentioning that any insurance etc will probably cease applying on the 90th day, as most travel/medical insurance won't cover you if you are in a country illegally.